# Having problems with nodes and tree structures (references/null pointers)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, artificial-intelligence, nodes

I'm having problems understanding how exactly to handle passing Nodes that contain children which might contain children and so on as part of the design of a tree structure.

My code is such that there are two objects, one is an object called "Tree", which is really just a "root" node with a lot of generic methods that act on the tree as a whole, and an object called node, which contains two string variables and a list of (children) nodes.

The node code :

```
public class Node {
    String type;
    String name;
    List<Node> children;
    /* Constructors and other methods */
```

That's really all the code necessary for the question.

To get to the heart of the question : how do I pass a copy of a node making it keep all of its data (so all of the children and children of children ..) but not having it "connected" to my previous node ? (in my understanding of java, if I were to pass say node.children to another method and then modify this children, it would modify it also in the previous node right?)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Without some code, it's hard to tell, but it sounds like you want to write some kind of recursive deep copy method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098362/how-to-deep-copy-a-tree

Comment: Hmm yes, is that the only way to do so ? cause it can get quite time consuming given my branching factor of ~2.3 .. If it is the only solution then I'll have to deal with it

Answer (score 1):

I believe Raedwald answer was correct (even though I expected there to be a more efficient solution) and therefore I am closing the question.

> Possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/16098362/how-to-deep-copy-a-tree – Raedwald

For those interested in the answer, my final algorithm (a general version of that given by Raedwald) is

```
public Node copy() {
    Node nodeCopy = new Node(this.getType(), this.getName());
    if (this.children != null) {
        for(int i=0; i < this.children.size(); i++)
            nodeCopy.children.add(this.getChild(i).copy());
    }
    return nodeCopy;
}
```